# EasyBCD not loading Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, easybcd

I have set up EasyBCD in a dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04, I have installed the Windows Boot Manager to the MBR and added an entry using the Grub2 option to load the Ubuntu partition, but it does not work, I get an error message similar to [this one](https://img.wonderhowto.com/img/70/05/63608409235871/0/minimal-bash-like-line-editing-is-supported-issue-while-installing-kali-linux-dual-boot.1280x600.jpg) when I choose Ubuntu from the menu.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by using LILO instead of GRUB and configuring EasyBCD to load that instead, I had to edit `/etc/lilo.conf` and replace lines with `root = /dev/sda3` and `boot = /dev/sda3`. Not perfect, but at least it works now. 
`